# How to update output file in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a  txt file named as nominal.txt open in read mode containing data as

```
JDON 2
SASF 1
DFKJ 3
PERTIM 1
KJKJK 0
```

And another file ss1.txt open in read mode containing data

```
6.2 0 ;AT P1
```

Another file nomdata.txt open in read mode containing data

```
101.1 210
```

Want to manipulate and write in output file pp 
 I want to have output file data like this

```
JDON 2
SASF 1
DFKJ 3
PERTIM 1.53000
KJKJK 0
```

`PERTIM 1.53300` is calculated as `6.2+101.1/101.1`
Please how to achieve this.
Want to be coded in python

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Did you try something?

Comment: Yes, i dont know how to solve this

Comment: I want a output file exactly as nominal.txt but i need to change the PERTIM value to be updated . Updation can be achieved by taking values from ss1.txt and nomdata.txt . Please help me to solve this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that your question is from your homework. I will just show some steps of the process and where you might want to go to find more information.

You can use Python's [with statement](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#with) to open files. It is possible to use nested with statements or a comma for opening multiple files.

```
with open('file1.txt', 'r') as file1, \
open('file2.txt', 'r') as file2, \
# and so on ...
open('filen.txt', 'r') as filen:
```

With your file open, you need to read each of its lines. This can be done with a [for statement](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-for-statement). Reading each line of a file return the line with a newline character at the end. You can use [rstrip](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.rstrip) to remove the \n at the end of the string then you can use [split](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) and a whitespace to "tokenize" your input. The following code is an example of the result obtained using this combination of functions.

```
>>> for line in file1:
...     print(line.rstrip().split(' '))
...
['JDON', '2']
['SASF', '1']
['DFKJ', '3']
['PERTIM', '1']
['KJKJK', '0']
```

You can use the same logic to read and parse the data from the other files. You should open the output file in write mode in order to write your changes. Also, you might want to read about how to convert a string to an [int value](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int).

Comment: can you give the full code to get the output

Comment: It is not working .I want to change only the pertim value value in the output. PERRTIM value is updated by taking values from ss1.txt and nomdata.txt. Please help

Comment: As I said, it seems that you are asking for a solution for your homework. I provided enough steps that you could use to get to the solution. You can update your question with more information about what you tried and what is not working out.